# Django error NoReverseMatch

Tags: python, django, url, view

I am using Django 1.8.3 and Python 3.4, I'm facing the below issue when clicking on a link on my website.

This is the error page :
[image: http://imgur.com/4HKlahP]

Project Directory:

```
* cacademy:
    * __pycache__
    * __init__
    * settings
    * urls
    * wsgi
* Classes:
    * __pycache__
    * migrations
    * static
    * __init__
    * admin
    * models
    * tests
    * urls
    * views
* templates:
    * cacademy:
        * base.html
        * classes_list.html
        * courses_detail.html
* db.sqlite3
* manage.py
```

My Models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class Course(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    teachername = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    teacherinfo = models.TextField()
    started_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

My Views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Course
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404

def classes_list(request):
    courses = Course.objects.filter(started_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('started_date')
    return render(request, 'cacademy/classes_list.html', {'courses': courses})

def course_detail(request, pk):
    course = get_object_or_404(Course, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'cacademy/courses_detail.html', {'course': course})
```

My Urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from Classes import views
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', views.classes_list, name='classes_list'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/Course/$', views.course_detail, name='Course_detail'),
    ]
```

classes_list.html:

```
 {% extends "cacademy/base.html" %}
 {% load staticfiles %}
 {% block content %}
         <div>
             <h2> Remember you can only register 3 Courses at once!</h2>
         </div>
     {% for course in courses %}
         <div course="post">
                 <div course="date">
                     {{ course.started_date }}
                 </div>
             <h1><a href="{% url 'course_detail' pk=Course.pk %}">{{ course.title }}</a></h1>
             <p>Taught by: {{ course.teachername|linebreaks }}</p>
         </div>
     {% endfor %}
 {% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your template url tag to

```
{% url 'course_detail' course.id %}
```

and in your urls.py

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/course/$', views.course_detail, name='course_detail')
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have assigned reverse name for courses detail url as `Course_detail` in `urls.py` but you are using the reverse name as `course_detail` in your template. It should have been `Course_detail` in the template.

Secondly, you are passing `pk` as `Course.pk` in your template. It should have been `course.pk` instead as you are using `course` variable when iterating over `courses` objects.

Instead use reverse name with lowercase initial to remove the case-sensitive issues.

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from Classes import views
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', views.classes_list, name='classes_list'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/Course/$', views.course_detail, name='course_detail'), # assign reverse name with lowercase initial letter
    ]
```

Then in your template, you can do this:

**classes_list.html**

```
{% extends "cacademy/base.html" %}
 {% load staticfiles %}
 {% block content %}
         <div>
             <h2> Remember you can only register 3 Courses at once!</h2>
         </div>
     {% for course in courses %}
         <div course="post">
                 <div course="date">
                     {{ course.started_date }}
                 </div>
             <h1><a href="{% url 'course_detail' pk=course.pk %}">{{ course.title }}</a></h1>
             <p>Taught by: {{ course.teachername|linebreaks }}</p>
         </div>
     {% endfor %}
 {% endblock content %}
```